# How to classify lines or paths in a noisy image

Tags: image, matlab, object, classification

I am trying to classify some paths (lines) on the following orthophoto: [image example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQrVW.png)
Initially, I tried with a Hough-transformation, e.g. as described here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13667/detecting-lines-with-houghlines-in-matlab.
However, this does not seem to work, partly because the edge-detection has a hard time locating the paths on the orthophoto, even after morphological filtering steps which should preserve the shapes I am after. I guess there are many options and methods that are worthwhile to try, but I am uncertain in which direction to look. I am most familiar with Matlab. Any suggestions (possibly with a supervised component, i.e., manually training a detection algorithm) would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance for your inputs

Comment: [this](https://github.com/trailbehind/DeepOSM) deep-learning approach seems promising. there are many papers about it as well, just google "deep aerial road detection" or similar phrase to find them

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive reply. I will pursue the function you link to.